# Static Instance of Interface as part of the interface

Tags: kotlin

Imagine I had an interface like:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun doSomething()
}
```

And I was interop-ing between Kotlin and Java. I now want a constant static instance of this interface but I want that to be part of the interface. I could do this:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun doSomething()
    companion object {
        val CONSTANT = object: MyInterface {
            override fun doSomething() { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

but that means I need to write `MyInterface.Companion.getCONSTANT()`. `@JvmField` doesn't work here.

I've also tried:

```
interface MyInterface {
    fun doSomething()
    object CONSTANT: MyInterface {
            override fun doSomething() { ... }
        }
    }
}
```

Which works in other Kotlin files (I can write `MyInterface.CONSTANT`) but I'd have to write `MyInterface.CONSTANT.INSTANCE` in Java. This solution seems the closest to what I want.

Any solutions? I want to be able to write `MyInterface.CONSTANT` in both Kotlin and Java and have them refer to a single `static final` object that implements the interface.

I believe I could also convert my Interface to an abstract class but that's the last resort.

Comment: You can try accessing the interface like MyInterface.CONSTANT instead of MyInterface.Companion.getCONSTANT()

Answer (score 1):

The issue of not being able to use `@JvmStatic` in interfaces is tracked in this ticket: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/oauth?state=%2Fissue%2FKT-6301

It is fixed by now and one [comment](https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-6301#comment=27-2683634) says

> Fix would be avaliable in 1.2.30 under '-language-version 1.3' option

Comment: What about `@JvmField`? I see it's being tracked here: https://youtrack.jetbrains.com/issue/KT-15807

Comment: But JvmStatic is what you need for Java Interop as described. The linked issue was fixed here: https://github.com/jetbrains/kotlin/commit/cc346aef64945012ab584e794e42454da03afe43 You can find an example at the bottom

Comment: `@JvmStatic` generates the getters like `getFooProp()` I'm looking for the behaviour of `@JvmField` where you can directly refer to `fooProp`

Comment: I believe if you do `@JvmField` for `vals` you don't have to write `Companion`, `@JvmStatic` is not needed.